# Is there any alternative to OpCache?

Tags: 8, caching, installation

I have a hosting with suPHP handler which doesn't support opcache. I want to start working on Drupal 8 sites which highly recommend opcache.

Is there any alternative to opcache? Should I change my hosting?

Comment: Sorry but this isn't really a questions for Drupal Answers, I know it's a Drupal website that's led you to ask the question, but the substance is just about PHP and not Drupal

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Any properly configured opcode cache should work. Notice that Drupal only currently checks for PHP Opcache in its requirements. Some people have got Drupal 8 working with [XCache](https://www.drupal.org/node/2630624), for example.

APC is really not the way to go. It exists in a backwards-compatible way in PHP 5.5 and as a token-based data cache (still useful, but it isn't an opcode cache in that configuration).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am able to install drupal 8 without Opcache although its recommended but not a dependency.

Answer (score 0):

You might consider using APC "http://php.net/manual/en/book.apc.php" as alternative to op-cache, op-cache is bundled with PHP by default in PHP 5.5.0 or later. so you should check with the hosting company if they support version 5.5.0 or later version of PHP.

Comment: My server's default php is 5.4 but it is running cloudlinux. I have selected php 5.5 for my site as a current version. Also enabled opcache but that is working since the php handler is suPHP which do not support op-cache.

Comment: I do not think that APC works with D8 core without need of a contrib project. And the APC project does not seem to have been ported it already.

Comment: Drupal 8 minimum requirement for PHP is 5.5.9 or higher. Then you should consider using a hosting with this minimum requirements.

Comment: The APC module is only for using APC as a cache backend for Drupal, not for using it as an OpCode cache, so it shouldn't make any odds that it's not got a D8 release yet.